# Do all bitmaps need the same amount of memory? How should I load them?

Tags: android

I've been working on an Android project lately, where I need to display many pictures.
So far I've been loading them into memory by using the BitmapFactory class. 
I have had trouble with out of memory exceptions. Here is my first question:

1. I have two images, both the same size (e.g. 150px * 150px). One of them takes much less memory (as png or jpg), because there are only very few colors displayed. Do they still both take the same amount of memory when loaded as a Bitmap? Should I load them differently?
2. Is there a way to save memory when loading images?(I'm loading it as sample size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you know that some files can be displayed with only the system's standard smaller color set, you can use Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 or Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. (Check this [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)) (You can set Bitmap.Config when first getting Bitmap object.) However, this is not recommended because this is more like a "compression with quality loss". When the Bitmap is in the memory (not file), then same-sized PNG files and BMP files take the same memory. PNG files will be uncompressed into BMP with transparency when loading from file into memory.
2. This Android official developer page exactly deals with what you are doing: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
3. This page may help you also.
   http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0):

A bitmap uses width x height x colour depth / 8 bytes constant.

If you  have 8bpp colour than every image will be 22500 bytes.
If you  have 32bpp colour than every image will be 90000 bytes.

If you are loading the images using an ImageInputStream where you have to pass a `byte[]` to the `image.load` method make sure that you set the size of the buffer correctly:
 `byte[] buff = new byte[22500]`.

Otherwise, you will get an out of memory exception.